# Set initial table width in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

When I add a new table with TinyMCE, the table is nearly invisible, because the initial width is just a few pixels.

Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open table.js, go to line 30 having content

```
width = formObj.elements['width'].value;
```

Change it to

```
width = formObj.elements['width'].value != "" ? formObj.elements['width'].value : 50;
```

Replace 50 with the default initial table width you want to set.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: +1 it is not a good thing to edit the tinymce core files, because you will have to keep this in mind everytime you update tinymce to the newest version, but it is a working solution (and i don't see another one (without much code to create a workaround))

Comment: There are several notes I did for myself, because of such small changes in libraries, that's okay for me. Fix is working thanks!

Comment: @Thariama **it is not a good thing to edit tinymce core files.....** totally agree with you

Answer (score 16):

In TinyMCE 4.x you can do this

```
tinymce.init({
plugins: "table",
table_default_styles: {
    width: '50%'
}
});
```

Comment: what about cellpadding and cellspacing? doesn't work if i add them there directly, any way to do that?

Comment: I put it in my CSS. table.mce-item-table TR {
    height: 1.5em;
}
table.mce-item-table TD {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 2px 5px;
} @msqar

Comment: A few hours after i asked you this, i found that same as table_default_styles there is a table_default_attributes that you can specify cellpadding and cellspacing. It's way cleaner instead of editing core files. Cya hope it helps to you too :)

Comment: thanks @msqar - the only thing about doing it that way AFAIK is that the attributes are then individually hard-coded into the html each table so you can't globally change them by changing a css declaration if you decide they need adjustment.

Comment: true story... in my case i needed them all to be default width: 100% and cellpadding: 5, cellspacing: 5. So it was useful for me haha :)

Answer (score 0):

This has been a while, but for me, simply setup a css rule that targets the tinymce table is good enough

```
/* Set up inital table width and height */
TABLE.mce-item-table TR {
    height: 50px;
}
TABLE.mce-item-table TD {
    width: 100px;
}
```